# Can Ether be mined directly into a contract?

Tags: contract-design, mining

For example, if I want a contract to automatically split the ether mined into different addresses instead of having a two step process whereby I first get the ether in an address in my wallet and then send it to a contract for further processing.

Comment: Just note the comment by `@Nicolas Massart` in the link - Calling a contract require more gas, so be sure either you solo mine (network looks to be unlimited on gas when sending rewards) or make sure that your pool put enough gas in the transaction.